# Typescript generic type with discriminator - runtime access to discriminator

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-erasure

I don't think this is possible but thought I'd ask. I have types with discriminator, eg:

```
type Fish={
  type: "fish"
  canSwim: boolean
}
type Bird={
  type: "bird"
  canFly: boolean
}
```

I have a state object such as:

```
const state={
  fish: /* a fish */
  bird: /* a bird */
}
```

I would like to write a function:

```
function getFromState<T>():T {
  return state[T.type] as T
}
```

Clearly a workaround is to pass the type as a parameter, eg:

```
function getFromState<T>(type):T {
  return state[type] as T
}
```

But then you end up repeating things:

```
const animal=getFromState<Fish>("fish")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think you already know, you can't refer to types at runtime because of [type erasure](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#erased-types).

There are many alternative paths, but it all depends on your actual use case. It's hard to know what your real needs are based on your question as written. I suggest you rewrite your question with your actual use case (states) rather than the abstract Animal). I'll make a guess as to your needs in this tentative answer, but will update it if you update your question and @ me above or comment below this answer.

In the code below runtime "polymorphism" is achieved with the discriminator property from your example (`type`) and regular `if`-`else` or `switch` logic. Because Typescript is able to [narrow types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) by inference, you also get compile-time static type safety. There is no DRY violation as in your workaround.

You can [test both its static type checking and its runtime behavior in the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgZwBZQLxQN4Cgq6qSALigCIAzRJEnPAYwEMA7AZQHc4BbYgIwHteANhCZYAvlgLQAQnABOAEzSYauScRLc586nigNGMASB78hI8RPDQAgo070BS+MigAfKDIVZLkKLfsCACpWCEr+HA4A2gDkktEAut5kAK6MtMBwvIxQAOYQwOEOABRqfnYRQSEAlMSFjti6svnJstmSaKjo0RTI0VAA-Jj4VsTdlNEANHpMbJzEwLLJ0KJQxBjDRFDRmgqT0wZG84vLYt60WQjAUJf0wNDoDXg9SMSR66VjvVP6s1z4x1BRFN3iMts89j92H8yA4EMt4lB6KFnEhIvEJiooDt5K8QZttloIUxDMZ-ktAcCNhBRtiiQdSTCBHDAQikR4tGjTlgUmkMllcvkYLJeBxmMBbhASqC6sFIAganU0cpcE1gC1sjc7pFJIkLNzUulMtkwIIQBxeLIwEg4LQYAa+YwikwArVyg4qsq8HAyFAnW6BAA6dqdLrgj2PXS4c6MBCCCABgS8HJFAAGAEkrgASDDOioByGcAZbfR9Ub6Ri8YDRFYIKEAQhTVUxKwgTOgEcj0djQgTSdTGag2dzDnzxKMReiJdWxaYFarKzIRgbTd04j1AHp11jKyhNTaqXokBBaABrOCMHKIxiKRaMDIcaAkE1Gc2W60IDgkKCsC0nhABrBNygAA5Hdz0vJA2W4CAIGyJpIAlRQigAEQAJQATSqADnzNC0rRtO1eSNIo8mAIURTFCUik+JBoiqSIAAZ4ibHDX3w217WI0jyNFcU7mo2l6IARmY7wgA).

```js
type Fish = {
    type: "fish"
    canSwim: boolean
}
type Bird = {
    type: "bird"
    canFly: boolean
}

type Animal = Fish | Bird

type AnimalTypes = Animal['type']

function getAnimal(type: AnimalTypes): Animal {
    return type === 'fish' ? { type: 'fish', canSwim: true } : { type: 'bird', canFly: true }
}

const state = {
    fish: { type: 'fish', canSwim: true } as Fish,
    bird: { type: 'bird', canFly: false } as Bird
}

function getFromState(type: AnimalTypes):Animal {
  return state[type]
}

function polymorphicFunction(animal: Animal) {
    if (animal.type === 'fish') {
        console.log(`It ${animal.canSwim ? 'can' : 'cannot'} swim!`)
    } else {
        console.log(`It ${animal.canFly ? 'can' : 'cannot'} fly!`)
    }
}

// both static type checking and runtime "polymorphism" works.
// Nothing has been repeated (DRY).
polymorphicFunction(getFromState('fish'))
polymorphicFunction(getFromState('bird'))
```

EDIT BY OP:
With @Inigo's help and answer to another question ([Typescript narrow parameter type based on discriminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70325393/typescript-narrow-parameter-type-based-on-discriminator)), a fuller solution was found using utility type `Extract`:

```
type Fish = {
    type: "fish"
    canSwim: boolean
}
type Bird = {
    type: "bird"
    canFly: boolean
}

type Animal = Fish | Bird

const state = {
    fish: [{ type: 'fish', canSwim: true }, { type: 'fish', canSwim: false }] as Fish[],
    bird: [{ type: 'bird', canFly: true }, { type: 'bird', canFly: false }] as Bird[]
}

function getFromState<C extends Animal["type"]>(type: C): Extract<Animal, {type: C}> {
    return state[type][0] as Extract<Animal, {type: C}>
}

getFromState("fish").canSwim // works
getFromState("bird").canFly // also works
getFromState("fish").canFly // error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgZwBZQLxQN4Cgq6qSALigCIAzRJEnPAYwEMA7AZQHc4BbYgIwHteANhCZYAvlgLQAQnABOAEzSYauScRLc586nigNGMASB78hI8RPDQAgo070BS+MigAfKDIVYstXowTAUAH0wNDo2LoUyMQA2hj4VsQA5FFISQA0ekxsnMTAsgCu0KKZ8WpQKZQZWSzsXFBkDgjFALpQ9AiwlDEt6SpQmgqxZYkVg-LV+obG+IXFpQlEY1qTTNPEjQLNUKJtHR5aPWLeZAWMtMBwflAA5hDAMLK8HMzAIRAAPADCUBAAHqFGPJOrZ7AIYiRJCQWgA+AAU5S+AEpiABRAGyegXD6gjgOUqI0Qw5S6WT3AqyRhBN6hGKSFoxAAMe066PyWOAOLseIEBNGXyJxywdweTxeNIgcPIlBISIAdPochwoAB6FVQVi8WQAawQwvuj2er3eUvGsoVayMqvVTV4Gq1uv1oqNEqlqXNUytat+siesiAA)

Comment: Thanks for answer @Inigo, I was not aware of the Animal['type'] trick. I guess this is as close as we can get. It's shame Typescript can't narrow the return type of getAnimal based on static analysis of the function. Thoughts on my second use case welcome ;)

Comment: @jugglingcats ok i updated my answer per the changes to your main example.  I don't understand your "It's a shame comment". No matter what, `getAnimal` has to take a parameter *you* specify. What difference does it make whether it is a generic type parameter or a type discriminator? The code is essentially the same and TS does infer the proper type... Have you examined my code in the playground? Look at the call at the end. TS is properly inferring the types!

Comment: @jugglingcats see my new comment at the end of my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your patience @Inigo. I did look at your playground example, and here is [my slightly modified version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgZwBZQLxQN4Cgq6qSALigCIAzRJEnPAYwEMA7AZQHc4BbYgIwHteANhCZYAvlgLQAQnABOAEzSYauScRLc586nigNGMASB78hI8RPDQAgo070BS+MigAfKDIVZLkKLfsCACpWCEr+HA4A2gDkktEAut5kAK6MtMBwvIxQAOYQwOEOABRqfnYRQSEAlMq6COzAtChF+FZQNdi6ugwI0NEUyNGEKl26svnJstkYrURQ-ZTRADR6TGycxMCyydCiUPShzigj3Qd9mgpDJ6NQ48CT07MQxNEX8surBkab27v7oZ55CNxBY8gVysVyJQSFUAHSSLBgwoCIpQ5Aw2H6dYcKAAelxUAgslkvFkWCAA). See next comment

Comment: It seems to me since the switch in my example is exhaustive, it is possible (at least in principle) for Typescript to infer the concrete return type from the argument. Note that I've not specified the return type explicitly and it correctly infers it is Fish | Bird. I'm not really a type system dude so I don't know whether this is possible in other languages!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70325393/typescript-narrow-parameter-type-based-on-discriminator

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70325393/typescript-narrow-parameter-type-based-on-discriminator) gave me some inspiration and I came up with:

```
type Fish = {
    type: "fish"
    canSwim: boolean
}
type Bird = {
    type: "bird"
    canFly: boolean
}

type Animal = Fish | Bird

const state = {
    fish: [{ type: 'fish', canSwim: true }, { type: 'fish', canSwim: false }] as Fish[],
    bird: [{ type: 'bird', canFly: true }, { type: 'bird', canFly: false }] as Bird[]
}

function getFromState<C extends Animal["type"]>(type: C): Extract<Animal, {type: C}> {
    return state[type][0] as Extract<Animal, {type: C}>
}

getFromState("fish").canSwim // works
getFromState("bird").canFly // also works
getFromState("fish").canFly // error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgZwBZQLxQN4Cgq6qSALigCIAzRJEnPAYwEMA7AZQHc4BbYgIwHteANhCZYAvlgLQAQnABOAEzSYauScRLc586nigNGMASB78hI8RPDQAgo070BS+MigAfKDIVYstXowTAUAH0wNDo2LoUyMQA2hj4VsQA5FFISQA0ekxsnMTAsgCu0KKZ8WpQKZQZWSzsXFBkDgjFALpQ9AiwlDEt6SpQmgqxZYkVg-LV+obG+IXFpQlEY1qTTNPEjQLNUKJtHR5aPWLeZAWMtMBwflAA5hDAMLK8HMzAIRAAPADCUBAAHqFGPJOrZ7AIYiRJCQWgA+AAU5S+AEpiABRAGyegXD6gjgOUqI0Qw5S6WT3AqyRhBN6hGKSFoxAAMe066PyWOAOLseIEBNGXyJxywdweTxeNIgcPIlBISIAdPochwoAB6FVQVi8WQAawQwvuj2er3eUvGsoVayMqvVTV4Gq1uv1oqNEqlqXNUytat+siesiAA)

Comment: Cool. But why does `state` contain arrays if you always just use the first of each type? Also, since this is built upon my answer, into which I put so much time ;), I wouldn't mind if you just edited my answer with this final solution ;)   It would be good for the community anyway to have one great answer. But also no worries if you don't want to do that. :)  I'm going to upvote the question because I think it is useful for future people.

Comment: Hi @Inigo, I followed your example regarding arrays in state. Interesting I can't seem to make them single item ([see playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgZwBZQLxQN4Cgq6qSALigCIAzRJEnPAYwEMA7AZQHc4BbYgIwHteANhCZYAvlgLQAQnABOAEzSYauScRLc586nigNGMASB78hI8RPDQAgo070BS+MigAfKDIVYstXowTAUAH0wNDo2LoUyMQY+FbEAORRSAkANHpMbJzEwLIArtCiUPQIsJSpKlCaCjFxRFAJ1fJpGQZGOfmFxaWe8mLeZHmMtMBwflAA5hDAMLK8HMzAIRAAPADCUBAAHqGM8qW29gIA2iSSJAC6AHwAFGpQawCUxACiO7L0IyuHHA7pGPc1qIrspdLJpnlZIwgktQsdJBdulA3rlPsBvnZfgJ-oDgVAAPT4zayOayfpAA))

Comment: I have edited your answer, hopefully it's okay. We are big fans of Princess Bride in this family btw... . Thanks again

Comment: I made them arrays because that's what you had in your question. I am sorry I am not as clever as Vizzini, but together we are! ;)