# Typescript narrow parameter type based on discriminator

Tags: typescript, type-safety

I have a legacy API as shown below ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwQQwHYBMCMUC8UDeAUFCVAMYLoBcUARAiFAGYCWATgM7DmIoa0AaYqWRsA5phpc2LVGKGkoosQCYaAIzhwANhDSEAvoUKhIsXmnQrcBYSQrU6DKBwhk4GHkkuC7zLVLAMnIKpOqiNKgArgjqEGyGxqbQ8N6eeKl8WFAAPuZpVsZMUahkwCweUBAAHm5RwBAAFA40mZYA2rQOtAC6AkriHFRojAD0AFRQAO5wUdroUNosANbQwHAuQR5i2ozJUMAAFiwcUOOjAJS2iu6oHDoQAHTacGKNyhwXiYQ1dQ2N9EYrE43HcBUEBAmUC0YFOCBOHFkYigYDYcFhZ1GBi+QA))...

```
type Command1 = {
    cmd: "my first command",
    arg1: string,
    arg2: boolean
}

type Command2 = {
    cmd: "my second command",
    foo: string,
    bar: number
}

type Command = Command1 | Command2

function execute(cmd: Command["cmd"], args:any /* would like to strongly type this */) {
    console.log(args)
}

execute("my first command", {/* oops missing props */})
```

Is there any way to type check the `args` param of the `execute` function without changing the parameter list of the function?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show some examples of `execute()` being called correctly? It’s not clear how you intend to map the properties of `Command` to the `args` parameter.

Comment: See answer from @tokland for examples, he nailed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Extract<Type, Union>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwQQwHYBMCMUC8UDeAUFCVAMYLoBcUARAiFAGYCWATgM7DmIoa0AaYqWRsA5phpc2LVGKGkoosQCYaAIzhwANhDSEAvoUKhIsXmnQrcBYSQrU6DKBwhk4GHkkuC7zLVLAMnIKpOqiNKgArgjqEGyGxqbQ8N6eeKl8WFAAPuZpVsZMUahkwCweUBAAHm5RwBAAPDBV1Q0YHPlZANq0DrQAugB8ABQONDACSuIcNADyCCzAjQCibWzIZc0WGFP45JQTUAZDU32UtEMAlLaK7qgcOhAAdNpwYmOUU8ocV4mENTqDRG9EYrE43HcBUEBGmEhotAA1hx0DDlGooEEotADH8AbUyPUICDnK57ugvFkYfsmAE6ABHADuEBh4TYNAALNZcYQgA)):

```
function execute<Cmd extends Command["cmd"]>(
  cmd: Cmd, 
  args: Omit<Extract<Command, { cmd: Cmd }>, "cmd">
) {
    console.log(cmd, args)
}

// execute<"my first command">(cmd: "my first command",   args: Omit<Command1, "cmd">): void
execute("my first command", { arg1: "ksd", arg2: true })

// execute<"my second command">(cmd: "my second command", args: Omit<Command2, "cmd">): void
execute("my second command", { foo: "qwe", bar: 123 })
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you. Hadn't come across Extract before. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwQQwHYBMCMUC8UDeAUFCVAMYLoBcUARAiFAGYCWATgM7DmIoa0AaYqWRsA5phpc2LVGKGkoosQCYaAIzhwANhDSEAvoUKhIsXmnQrcBYSQrU6DKBwhk4GHkkuC7zLVLAMnIKpOqiNKgArgjqEGyGxqbQ8N6eeKl8WFAAPuZpVsZMUahkwCweUBAAHm5RwBAAPDBV1Q0YHPlZANq0DrQAugB8ABQONDACSuIcNADyCCzAjQCibWzIZc0WGFP45JQTUAZDU32UtEMAlLaK7qgcOhAAdNpwYmOUU8ocV4mENTqDRG9EYrE43HcBUEBGmEhotAA1hx0DDlGooEEotADH8AbUyPUICDnK57ugvFkYfsmAE6ABHADuEBh4TYNAALNZcYQgA)

Answer (score 0):

How about using an intersection type with generics for this? I'm assuming the rest of the code is the same as your example:

```
function execute<T extends Command["cmd"]>(cmd: T, args: Command & { cmd: T }) {
    console.log(cmd, args)
}
```

I can't think of a better way of "gluing" together the discriminator and the right type of `Command`.

Comment: Couldn't quite get this to work right but thanks. See answer by @tokland